# C# parallel, how to set threads number

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to run a part of code in parallel.
currently i'm using  `Parallel.For`

how  to  make 10, 20 or 40  threads running at the same time

my current code is:

```
        Parallel.For(1, total, (ii) =>
            {
                doJob(ii);
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option:

```
ParallelOptions opts = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20}

Parallel.For(1, total,opts, (ii) =>
    {
        doJob(ii);
    });
```

But I encourage you to read the documentation as it states some interesting facts you need to take into account, for example:

> By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the
>   underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from
>   the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

Also, it provides a little bit of guidance:

> The setting exists predominantly to provide control for advanced
>   usage. For example, if you know that a particular algorithm you're
>   using won't scale beyond a certain number of cores, you can set the
>   MaxDegreeOfParallelism property to avoid wasting cycles on additional
>   cores. Or, if you're running multiple algorithms concurrently and want
>   to manually divide up how much of the system they could utilize, you
>   can set a MaxDegreeOfParallelism value for each.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Parallel.For(1, total, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
  (ii) =>
  {
    doJob(ii);
  });
```